# Storing html in filesystem or database

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-storage, local-storage, storage

I'm building a Forum/kind of like Wikipedia where users have a rich text editor and can upload images. I thought about saving that "text"(Prosemirror html) as a text file in a Filesystem(Google Cloud Storage) instead of a String in a mysql database. Because then, I would not have to limit the String / and it would be cheaper storing that text. I would then use mysql to reference to that file to still keep relations.

Would this be a good practice or am I missing something ?

Comment: You can download a wikipedia mechanism (a wiki) to make your own wikipedia shaped information website, ready made...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have developed something similar in the past and believe the practice is sound. A couple of pointers, save the files in some structure to improve lookup speed and allow for easier pruning (cleanup) in the future. For example:

\forumhtml\year\month\day\category\

Also be sure to encode the text/html (base64) so you don't run into any issues posting through any APIs.